# Extracting Data From XML with VBA

Tags: xml, vba

As a bit of a background, im a fairly new person to coding. its been pretty much 10 years since i last 'coded' so please go easy ;).

Im currently trying to exctract data from an XML file below:

```
- <IPNumber IPNumber="5">
- <Band Band="1">
- <Channel Channel="1">
  <CMPWRE>0.123456</CMPWRE> 
  <CMPWIM>0.234567</CMPWIM> 
  </Channel>
- <Channel Channel="2">
  <CMPWRE>-0.123456</CMPWRE> 
  <CMPWIM>0.234567</CMPWIM> 
  </Channel>
  </Band>
- <Band Band="2">
- <Channel Channel="1">
  <CMPWRE>0.123456</CMPWRE> 
  <CMPWIM>0.234567</CMPWIM> 
  </Channel>
  </Band>
</IPNumber5>
- <IPNumber IPNumber="6">
- <Band Band="1">
- <Channel Channel="1">
  <CMPWRE>0.123456</CMPWRE> 
  <CMPWIM>0.234567</CMPWIM> 
  </Channel>
- <Channel Channel="2">
  <CMPWRE>-0.123456</CMPWRE> 
  <CMPWIM>0.234567</CMPWIM> 
  </Channel>
  </Band>
- <Band Band="2">
- <Channel Channel="1">
  <CMPWRE>0.123456</CMPWRE> 
  <CMPWIM>0.234567</CMPWIM> 
  </Channel>
  </Band>
</IPNumber6>
```

At the moment im wanting the user to chose which IPnumber, Channel and Band they want.. then i want to extract the CMPWRE & CMPWIM data for each in a list like below:

```
IPNumber 'X'
Band     'X'
Channel  'X'
CMPWRE   'XXX'
CMPWIM   'XXX'
```

Here is a short snippet of code that im trying to use to extract the data, but im just getting no luck getting it to work.

Code:

```
Set oXML = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
oXML.async = False
oXML.Load ("H:\14-13-21.xml")


Dim LgChan As String
Dim LgChan1 As String
Dim LgChan2 As String
**Dim LgChan3 As String
Dim LgChan4 As String**

Dim Test As Integer 
Dim Test2 As Integer
Dim Test3 As Integer

Test = mobelenum0.Value ' User Box on GUI where a value is inputted E.G. the number 5
Test2 = FeedSubBand.Value ' User Box on GUI where a value is inputted E.G. the number 1 
Test3 = LogicChannel.Value ' User Box on GUI where a value is inputted E.G. the number 1


LgChan = "TableContents/IPModuleNumber[@IPModuleNumber='1']"
LgChan1 = "//TableContents/IPModuleNumber/FeederSubBand[@FeederSubBand=" & Test2 & "]"
LgChan2 = "//TableContents/IPModuleNumber/FeederSubBand/LogicalChannel[@LogicalChannel=" & Test3 & "]" 
**LgChan3 = "//TableContents/IPModuleNumber/FeederSubBand/LogicalChannel[@LogicalChannel=" & Test3 & "]/CMPWRE"
LgChan4 = "//TableContents/IPModuleNumber/FeederSubBand/LogicalChannel[@LogicalChannel=" & Test3 & "]/CMPWIM"**

 Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B101").Value = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(LgChan).NodeTypedValue
 Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B102").Value = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(LgChan1).nodeTypedValue
 Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B103").Value = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(LgChan2).nodeTypedValue
**Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B104").Value = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(LgChan3).nodeTypedValue
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B105").Value = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(LgChan4).nodeTypedValue**
```

im struggling to get the code so that if a differend band is selected then obviously the channel value will change... same again with the IPNumber change filtering down through.

Any help would be great!

Smerf

Comment: Do you have control over the xml layout? <IPNumber IPNumber="6"></IPNumber6> by my way of thinking is not valid XML. That won't help any kind of parser

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add code that catches the event "when a different band is selected".
That code depends on how the user selects the band, but if the band is selected from a Combobox in a Userform, you would catch the Combobox_Change event, something like this:

```
Private Sub FeedSubBand_Change()
    DisplayBands
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
If the band is selected by the user pressing an *Execute* button, you should use the button's Click event, like this:

```
Private Sub ExecuteButton_Click()
        DisplayBands
End Sub
```

As you suggest, it is important to be aware of performance issues here.  If the XML file is big, reading it will take a long time.  It is then a good idea to do as you are doing, have the document read only when the user specifically asks for it by pressing a button.  Another option would be to auto-read each time one of the textboxes changes, but that would not be good if the XML document is big.

Comment: GTG, thanks for your response.
The user inputs a number from a text box on a userform, so i will tinker about with what you have suggested to see what i can do

Comment: GTG, thanks for your response. The user inputs several numbers initially in to a number of text boxes and then clicks an 'execute' button on the GUI. 
the ComboBox_change only seems to be useful if it is changed by the user during opperation?

im hoping that i am able to do this task as almost a treeview type search, but maybe i may have to extract all the data from IPNumber "X" in to memory, then do a sub search for Band "X" then load all of Band "X" results in to memory and repeat... but this seems VERY memory hungy and a process 'muncher'.. which is something i wish not to happen.

Comment: GTG. im dealing with about 30 XML files ranging from 1mb to 3mb each so its a HUGE amount of data that i have to sift through.

Comment: this is why i would like to try and search using a 'tree view' type search. 
the GUI i have expects the user to input several different numbers,
I then use these numbers to search the XML files to extract information regarding certain mathematical data... This data is then put through my own algorythm and it should 'spit out' 8 end values which the user should be able to use in their next sequence of job.

Comment: Seems to me that it would be a good idea to read the file once and keep it in memory.